# newcommand for subsubsubsection

Tags: macros, sectioning

I have created a command for the subsubsubsection like:

```
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

But now I have a title with a long text.

I now the command `\paragraph` have `\paragraph[short title]{title}` version.

How can I modify my declaration to use both `\subsubsubsection{title}` and `\subsubsubsection[short title]{title}`?

Comment: Have a look at xparse package.

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\subsubsubsection}{O{#2}m}{\paragraph[#1]{#2}}` with a quite recent version of  `\usepackage{xparse}` or `\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph`

Comment: Instead of that mix stuff, why don't you just adjust paragraph such that there is a line break after it. That is quite easy and then use the `\let` trick Christian mentioned.

Comment: @daleif: The `\let` trick would be the easiest way, yes. alas, there's this `\mbox`stuff :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's why is ask why not just adjust paragraph. This is more like everything looks like a nail if you have a hammer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the class file for the definition of `\paragraph`; for instance, in `article.cls` you find

```
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

What you want is to change sign to the value in the fourth argument to `\@startsection` and possibly changing the fifth argument to give smaller vertical space, so you add to your preamble something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus-1ex \@minus-.2ex}%
                                    {0.5ex \@plus .1ex}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph
```

Adding `\mbox{}\\` is definitely the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

With a recent version of `xparse`, the `O` optional argument can be initialized with `#3` being the 3rd argument here, so `\paragraph[#2]{#3}` will work.

The `#1` is reserved for the starred version, so `\subsubsubsection*` is possible as well here.

If `\paragraph` should be used as well, this approach however is not recommended, due to the counter issues.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\subsubsubsection}{sO{#3}m}{
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \paragraph*{#3}\mbox{}%

  }{%
    \paragraph[#2]{#3}\mbox{}%

  }%
}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foobar}
\subsubsection{Foofoobar}
\subsubsubsection{Foofoofoobar}

\subsubsubsection[Short foo]{Foofoofoobar}

\subsubsubsection*{Not in ToC and unnumbered} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need an own counter and a resetting for `\subsubsubsection` if you also want to use the `\paragraph` as as usual.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=4,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  counterwithin=subsubsection
]{subsubsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[level=5]{paragraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[level=6]{subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\subsection{foo}
\subsubsection{foo}
\subsubsubsection[FOO]{foo}
\paragraph{foo}

\section{bar}
\subsection{bar}
\subsubsection{bar}
\subsubsubsection[BAR]{bar}
\paragraph{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]